# Powershell WMI ROOT\MicrosoftExchangev2, and WQL where usage

Tags: powershell, wmi, exchange-server, wql

(PS Version 1)

```
PS C:\> $query = 'Select * From Exchange_PublicFolder WHERE Path LIKE "/Foo%"'
PS C:\> $query
Select * From Exchange_PublicFolder WHERE Path LIKE "/Foo%"
PS C:\> gwmi -namespace ROOT\MicrosoftExchangev2 -query $query
Get-WmiObject : Provider is not capable of the attempted operation
At line:1 char:5
+ gwmi  <<<< -namespace ROOT\MicrosoftExchangev2 -query $query
```

It makes no difference if I try to assign the query to a variable first or not.  Is there might be a problem with the WQL keyword WHERE?  I can run a query without it just fine:

```
PS C:\> (gwmi -namespace ROOT\MicrosoftExchangev2 -query  "Select * From Exchange_PublicFolder").count
711
```

It wouldn't be a huge deal to filter later in the pipeline, but I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here :)

Comment: Google hints that this is actually something bubbling up from the arcane WMI system but I'm not finding much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing something wrong, it's just that the provider is not capable of processing your query (as the error states). It seems that using LIKE against any property is not supported, you can use "=" but it's not what you're looking for :(.
IMO, using Where-Object is the way to go in this case.