# How can I tell what WQL operators are supported on a class using powershell?

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

So the WQL LIKE operator isn't supported on my WMI class from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580133/powershell-wmi-root-microsoftexchangev2-and-wql-where-usage).  How do I tell ahead of time, or interactively as I write, what is/is not supported?  I'd like to stick with Powershell here and avoid other solutions like wmic.

Answer (score 0):

I can only find one mention of LIKE not working, and that is on old systems.  LIKE was added in XP and Server 2003.  It will not work on older machines.  This applies to the machine you are grabbing the WMI object from.